# Redirect all URLs without `www.`

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm using below .htaccess code to add www to all URLs without www, on my current server it's working fine but since I changed my hosting to godaddy there is a problem as images on my website are not loading! When I'm removing this htaccess file then everything is fine.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.zire20.ir$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.zire20.ir/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /view_basket.php?order_id=$1&pin=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably change your rule to the following, and add the condition to ensure files don't get rewritten:

```bsh
# Make sure the request doesn't point to a file first
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /view_basket.php?order_id=$1&pin=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Please check your Apache error logs to see what is causing the issue.

Comment: The "internal server error" is caused by the line-end comment. Remove `# Make sure the...` (everything after `!-f`).